# How to create mesh on cylindrical surface after generating random points on cylindrical surface

Tags: matlab, 3d, triangulation, point-clouds, delaunay

Now I can generate random points on cylindrical surface.
But I cannot create correctly the mesh on cylindrical surface by using generated points. 
When I use this code, the triangle mesh created by delaunay triangulation becomes vertically long.
So I want to solve this problem.

I show my code here.
I don't want to change the parameters except for number of points

```
     clear all
     close all
     clc

     n =1000;          % Number of points

     % Radius
     c = 3.0*10^8;      % Speed of lgiht
     f = 5.2*10^9;      % Frequency
     lambda = c/f;      % Wavelength
     r = 3*lambda;      % Radius of circular cylinder
     theta = rand(1,n)*(2*pi); 


     % Equation
     x = r.*cos(theta);
     y = r.*sin(theta);
     z = 2*rand(n,1)-1;

     % Plot
     figure(1)
     scatter3(x(:), y(:), z(:),'.')

     % axis equal
     xlabel('x-length','Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',25)
     ylabel('y-length','Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',25)
     zlabel('z-length','Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',25)
     title('Randomly distributed point cloud on surface of cylinder','Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',25)

     % Plot range
       xlim([-1 1])     % Plot range of x-axis
       ylim([-1 1])     % Plot range of y-axis
       zlim([-1 1])     % Plot range of z-axis
       set(gca,'Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',20)

     % Create mesh
     figure(2)
     dt = delaunayTriangulation(x(:),y(:),z(:));
    [tri, Xb] = freeBoundary(dt);
     tr = TriRep(tri, Xb);
     P = incenters(tr);
     fn = faceNormals(tr);
     trisurf(tri,Xb(:,1),Xb(:,2),Xb(:,3), ...
 'FaceColor', 'g', 'faceAlpha', 0.8);
     axis equal;
     hold on;
     quiver3(P(:,1),P(:,2),P(:,3), ...
  fn(:,1),fn(:,2),fn(:,3),0.5, 'color','r');
     hold off;
     xlabel('x-length','Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',25)
     ylabel('y-length','Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',25)
     zlabel('z-length','Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',25)
     title('Randamly distributed point cloud on surface of cylinder','Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',25)
   % Plot range
     xlim([-1 1])     % Plot range of x-axis
     ylim([-1 1])     % Plot range of y-axis
     zlim([-1 1])     % Plot range of z-axis
     set(gca,'Fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',20)
```

Please teach me the cause that the mesh becomes vertically long.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have a question. What do you mean 'separately'? I can create the cylinder. Did you run my code?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by 'vertically long'?

Comment: Thank you for replying to me, Jigg. Did you run my code? When this code is run, the mesh of triangle becomes long to the z-axis direction. I want to solve this problem. You can confirm that the triangle mesh is 'vertically long' when you zoom figure2.